# OAuth2 resource server

Tags: spring-security-oauth2

Is am bit confused with OAuth2 resource server implementation. For any application we can have multiple microservices like for supplier, product, inventory etc and if we are implementing OAuth2 then I know there will be only 1 authentication server required for the authentication purpose but not sure if each microservice (Product, Supplier etc) will have the resource server implementation to check if the user is authorized or not for accessing the respective microservice, if it is not the case then how a single resource server can be used for all the microservices.

Think we are implementing Oauth2 using spring framework and using @PreAuthorize annotation on the exposed endpoints of the microservices.

Comment: Why don't you use the API gateway in front of all the services and put authorization verification code in API gateway itself..

Comment: API Gateway will be there for the routing purpose like zuul and cannot own the OAuth2 responsiblity

Comment: If you need to check the authorization at individual service level, then you can think of claim based authorization. This link can be useful for you. https://www.davideguida.com/handling-authentication-and-authorization-in-microservices-part-2/

Comment: Thanks Ajay, but this solution is not following the OAuth2 completely. As you can see in this solution request reached to the microservice which in turn calls the authorization service to verify the user permission, which is not correct as microservice gets exposed even to the unauthorized user and secondly an unnecessary call to microservice gets added in the scenario of unauthorized user.